# How to change the font in the theme apex oracle 21

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an application that is written in the apex oracle environment, but I want to change the font in this application (for example on "Calibri". I downlad this font:
[image]

But I can't find how to do it.
I also tried to Theme Roller the css in the topic with the help of this code, but it did not help.
[image]

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: CSS you posted in the 2nd screenshot (Theme Roller) works just fine on my Apex 20.2.

Comment: @Littlefoot yes, I understood it, below there was a syntactic error, and you will not prompt where it is possible to find the list of fonts for use in apex (2 way)??I understand that not all fonts can be used?

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry. I'm happy with default font Oracle provides for Apex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add your custom font to Oracle APEX by following the next steps (tried with `.otf` file not `.ttf`):

1. Add the `.otf` file to your application **Static Application Files** (for example: `your-custom-font.otf`)
2. Add an **Application item** called `FONT`
3. Create an **Application process**:

- Process Point: `On Load: Before Header (page template header)`
- Code

```sql
begin
    :FONT := '<style type="text/css">
     @font-face {
      font-family: "DefaultFont";
      src: url(#APP_IMAGES#your-custom-font.otf);
    }
    body {
        font-family: "DefaultFont" !important;
    }

    .ui-widget {
       font-family: "DefaultFont" !important;
    }
   </style> ';
end;
```

4. On every page where you want to use this custom font, on page level section **HTML Header** > **HTML Header** set the substitution string `&FONT`.

The described process is very helpful if you need different fonts for different users, but if all your users have the same font. Then you just need following **Inline CSS** to the page:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: "DefaultFont";
 src: url(#APP_IMAGES#your-custom-font.otf);
}
body {
   font-family: "DefaultFont" !important;
}

.ui-widget {
  font-family: "DefaultFont" !important;
}
```

Or for Calibri add this CSS:

```css
body {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif !important;
}
```

Also when choosing font consider [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp).

Comment: Hello, Is it possible use one css to all page in your example I must put to my all page --> inline css above code.

Comment: Please, use Theme Roller. Add this code above i Custom CSS section, and it will be applied on all pages.